# redirect to custom php template in wordpress plugin directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i create a plugin that contain :

- index.php
- includes :
  index.php
  style.css

i wanna create a plugin that when user active it , it redirect user to includes/index.html

i wrote somthing like this

```
if(!function_exists(theme_redirect)) {
 function theme_redirect () {
   $options = get_option('option');
    if(isset($options['redirect'])) {
     $redirect = $options['redirect'];
     }
    else {
     $redirect = false;
     }

     if($options['redirect'] == 1) {
       include_once 'includes/index.php';
       exit;
     }
    }
   add_action (wp_header,'theme_redirect');
  }
```

but when it redirected , it shows just html tag style never include
i attached styles in includes/index.php with
">

anyone can help me to include with another way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter hook

> This filter hook is executed immediately before WordPress includes the predetermined template file.
>
> This can be used to override WordPress's default template behavior.